# Possible runtime error with while loop-Polyspace

Tags: memory, embedded, runtime-error, static-analysis

I am working with Embedded C language and recently run the MathWorks Polyspace Code Prover (Formal Methods static analysis) for the whole project to check for critical runtime errors. It found one bug (Red finding) at While loop where I am copying some ROM data into RAM via memory registers.
The code is working fine and as expected but I would like to ask if there is any solution to safely remove this warning. Please find the code example below:

```
register int32 const *source;
uint32 i=0;
uint32 *dest;
source= (int32*)&ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN;
dest = (uint32*)&ADDR_ARAM_BEGIN;

    if ( source != NULL )
    {
        while ( i < 2048 )
        {
            dest[i] = (uint32)source[i];
            i++;
        }
     }
```

My guess is that `ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN` and `ADDR_ARAM_BEGIN` are defined in linker script and polyspace didn't compile and link the project that is why it is complaining about the possible run time error or infinite loop.

`ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN` and `ADDR_ARAM_BEGIN` are defined as extern in the respective header file.

```
extern uint32_t ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN;
extern uint32_t ADDR_ARAM_BEGIN;
```

The warning is red and exact warning is as follow:

> ```
> Check:    Non-terminating Loop
> Detail:   The Loop is infinite or contains a run-time error
> Severity: Unset
> ```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "It found one bug at While loop" What's the message? How do you know it's a bug?

Comment: "Infinite loop or runtime error". there is no compiler or linker error.

Comment: To answer you precisely, could you add the definition of ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN and ADDR_ARAM_BEGIN? By the way, do you see a red check or an orange one (you are using the term "warning") ?

Comment: @codetest : You need to provide the exact verbatim diagnostic in your question, not paraphrase it in the comments.  Edit the question, copy & paste the diagnostic.

Comment: @AlexDeba I edit my post. I hope it will make the problem more clear.

Comment: I think the "non-terminating loop" test fails because if `dest == NULL`, a run-time error occurs before the loop terminates. Not admittedly the most helpful of diagnostics.  It seems the cost of a tool is often inversely proportional to its ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

The code is overall quite fishy.

**Bugs**

- `if ( source != NULL )`. You just set this pointer to point at an address, so it will obviously not point at NULL. This line is superfluous.
- You aren't using `volatile` when accessing registers/memory, so if this code is executed multiple times, the compiler might make all kinds of strange assumptions. This might be the cause of the diagnostic message.

**Bad style/code smell** (should be fixed)

- Using the `register` keyword is fishy. This was once a thing in the 1980s when compilers were horrible and couldn't optimize code properly. Nowadays they can do this, and far better than the programmer, so any presence of `register` in new source code is fishy.
- Accessing a register or memory location as `int32` and then casting this to unsigned type doesn't make any sense at all. If the data isn't signed, then why are you using a signed type in the first place.
- Using home-brewed `uint32` types instead of `stdint.h` is poor style.

**Nit-picks** (minor remarks)

- The `(int32*)` cast should be `const` qualified.
- The loop is needlessly ugly, could be replaced with a for loop:

  ```
  for(uint32_t i=0; i<2048; i++)
  {
    dest[i] = source[i];
  }
  ```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for the detailed analysis. I will definitely adapt your suggestions.

Comment: This is a critique of the code, not an answer to the question. 
 Are you perhaps not aware of what PolySpace is?

Comment: @Clifford Yet another mostly broken static analyser full of false positives. A working tool should not make assumptions about declarations not visible, it should demand a project-wide setup. Although the OP kind of gave the impression that the diagnostics came from dynamic analysis, which makes even less sense.

Comment: @Lundin : PolySpace is not a traditional static analyser.  It uses _abstract execution_ to capture the kind of bugs you might otherwise find in dynamic analysis, except without "getting lucky" by happening to execute an error path.  It is not only (in fact seldom) used on whole systems but can be used for testing partial systems.  In this case it is saying "_this code will fail for certain values of the unknown variable or parameter_" which is true - on its own the code is unsafe while in context it may never fail.  The tool is not broken, rather the result not understood.

Comment: @Lindin : Aparently one of the first uses of PolySpace was to detect the bug that caused the ESA Ariane 5 rocket to explode on launch in 1996.  Unfortunately the tool was applied after the event - you bet your life it is used routinely now, and in many safety critical systems.  What confuses me is that when I used PolySpace it was >£20,000 a seat - for that I would have expected support from the vendor not SO!  I certainly would not recommend using it without attending the accompanying training course.

Comment: @Clifford If the tool says "infinite loop or run-time error", it is giving a false diagnostic, period. I have tried enough of these programs, from the >£20k flavour to the cheap ones, to know that this is still a market filled to the brim with quacks. I also don't think I have been on any seminary or tool demonstration regarding safe software where they did not speak of Ariane 5... If you paid £20k to detect that bug you were scammed hard, because gcc with `-WConversion` does it for free.

Comment: @Lundin : The issue here is lack of understanding of the tool rather than the tool being wrong.  The tool is simply giving an answer to a different question than the user or you thinks is being asked of it.  It does not for example perform the same checks as -Wconversion.  To think that is to misunderstand what the tool does.  In fact, static analysis is best used in conjunction with PolySpace, not instead of it.

Comment: @Clifford you are correct. I am using PRQA QAC for static analysis and Polyspace in conjunction for dynamic analysis. I asked this question because I simply think  these registers are assigned from linker script and this is the reason polyspace complains. I know this for sure that Polyspace is not considering linker script.

Comment: It has been a long time since I used PolySpace, but it seems the name is now used for two products - "Code Prover" and "Bug Finder" - the latter appears to be a more traditional static analysis tool - presumably we are referring to "Code Prover" here?

Comment: @Clifford yes, I am referring to Code prover.

Answer (score 1):

the reason why Polyspace is giving a red error here is that `source` and `dest` are pointers to a uint32. Indeed, when you write:

```
source= (int32*)&ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN
```

you take the address of the variable `ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN` and assign it to `source`.

Hence both pointers are pointing to a buffer of 4 bytes only.
It is then not possible to use these pointers like arrays of 2048 elements.
You should also see an orange check on `source[i]` giving you information on what's happening with the pointer `source`.

It seems that `ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN` and `ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN` are actually containing addresses.
And in this case, the code should be:

```
source = (uint32*)ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN;
dest   = (uint32*)ADDR_ARAM_BEGIN;
```

If you do this change in the code, the red error disappears.

Comment: your explanation makes sense. I will make changes and run the test next week. thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If PolySpace does not know the value `ADDR_ARAM_BEGIN` it will assume it could be NULL (or any other value value for its type).  While you explicitly test for `source` being NULL, you do not do the same for `dest`.

Since both `source` and `dest` are assigned from linker constants and in normal circumstances neither should be NULL it is unnecessary to explicitly test for NULL in the control flow and an [`assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) would be preferable - PolySPace recognises assertions, and will apply the constraint in subsequent analysis, but `assert()` resolves to nothing when `NDEBUG` is defined (normally in release builds), so does not impose unnecessary overhead:

```
const uint32_t* source = (const uint32_t*)&ADDR_SWR4_BEGIN ;
uint32_t* dest = (uint32_t*)&ADDR_ARAM_BEGIN;

// PolySpace constraints asserted
assert( source != NULL ) ;
assert( dest != NULL ) ;

for( int i = 0; i < 2048; i++ )
{
    dest[i] = source[i] ;
}
```

An alternative is to provide PolySpace with a "forced-include" (`-include` option) to provide explicit definitions so that PolySpace will not consider all possible values to be valid in its analysis. That will probably have the effect of speeding analysis also.

Comment: However, note that the use of `assert` is often banned by coding standards. It would be preferable to use standard C `static_assert` in this case, since the check is nonsense and clutter anyhow. Does Polyspace support standard C?

Comment: @Lundin : I think you can specify a "custom assert" for PolySpace - it does not have to do anything, it just has to be recognised as a "guarantee".  So for example you could define `PSASSERT( x)` as an empty macro, but tell PolySpace to treat it as a guarantee.  Or you may already have a custom assert wrapper that might be used.  The forced include option with dummy definitions is often preferable, as it does not clutter the real code if you are not to have asserts at all - it is also an appropriate place to define a dummy assert in any case.